# Missing Tax in admin

Tags: magento-1.8, tax

For some strange reason when I now log into my admin I am missing the the tax pages. I thought it could be a ACL issue however I am an administrator and resource access is set to all.

Any one got any ideas how I can get it back?

Comment: Flush the cache(s). Logout and login again to confirm the issue.

Comment: Flushed all the caches however the issue still exists

Comment: Next thing I can think of is that you just installed a module and something has override and killed it. I'm assuming we are on about Tax under Sales?

Comment: Yea correct, Tax under Sales. I am now in the middle of disabling all non essentional extensions

Comment: It looks like its within the database as if I change the db to an older version then it show up